# Transfer a class via Bluetooth between two iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, bluetooth, transfer

I have a class C with all the data in it. The class C is initialled in cell phone A and the variables (including number, string, array) are assigned value by operating cell phone A. And now I want to transfer all the data in class C to cell phone B by Bluetooth. Is that possible to transfer the whole class from A to B via bluetooth instead of transferring data one by one?

Comment: I think you want to transfer an instance (object) not a class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to transfer it by breaking it down into bits. The question is how you get the class to work on the other device, which I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

In cell phone A serialize the class C via `NSKeyedArchiver`, transfer the serialized data to cell phone B, de-serialize  with `NSKeyedUnarchiver` into a new instance of the class C.

You will have to implement the `NSCoder` methods `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder` in your class C.

As for transferring the code itself, that is not viable because apps are not able to convert data to code and execute it (unless you are Apple).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer sounds reasonable to me. But I am a beginner on this, can you offer some simple code? For example, the class is named as Settings.h, variables include int aa, double bb, bool cc, NSString dd.

Comment: @user3593888 Go look at the documentation and examples related to NSKeyedUnarchiver.  If you have a specific question after reading that, ask a new question on SO.   Not meant to be harsh; but this is something you really need to be able to figure out at least the basics of using the documentation, etc, if you are to be successful with programming.